Confused about NpgSql connection pooling vs AddDbContextPool
I'm trying to implement database pooling in my .net core application that's connecting to PostgreSql db. While reading documentation on NpgSql, It states that pooling is avaible in the this library (https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html) . EntityFrameworkCore also has AddDbContextPool for pooling db connection.
I'm confused about this.
Will this still pool the connection?
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));

Or do I have to do this to pool connection?
services.AddDbContextPool<MyContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connectionString));


AddDbContextPool doesn't affect connection pooling. DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. Pooling them makes sense if you don't want to pay the (usually small) penalty of recalculating the DbSet metadata. The real cost is establishing database connections and closing them. Connection pooling helps by resetting connections instead of closing them, thus releasing any locks or resources, but still leaving them open so they can be reused. It's on by default and controlled by the connection string

In short, you don't have to do anything, NpgSql uses connection pooling by default. Only look at context pooling if you have real high-traffic scenarios and you want to squeeze every bit of performance. That's explained in the Advanced Performance Topics - DbContext Pooling docs

Just use .AddDbContext and let NpgSQL use connection pooling automatically. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit-of-Work. AddDbContextPool doesn't affect connection pooling at all.
Connection Pooling
You don't have to do anything to get connection pooling, NpgSql uses connection pooling by default. The Basic Features NpgSQL docs say as much:

Therefore, Npgsql connections are pooled by default: closing or disposing a connection doesn't close the underlying physical connection, but rather returns it to an internal pool managed by Npgsql

Connection Pooling is one of the most important performance features and should be used if available. Most database drivers use connection pooling. When the application closes the connection, the driver actually resets the connection, rolling back any transactions and releasing any resources or locks used on the server and puts it in a pool of connections that can be uses again. That's why it's so important to NOT keep connections open for long and definitely not use a single global connection.
Context Pooling
Context pooling on the other hand is an advanced performance feature only meant for high-performance scenarios. A DbContext is a lightweight Unit-of-Work and doesn't even use any connections unless it has to read or store data. When that happens, the connections are closed immediately.
The EF docs explain this in the Advanced Performance Topics: Context Pooling section:

A DbContext is generally a light object: creating and disposing one doesn't involve a database operation, and most applications can do so without any noticeable impact on performance. However, each context instance does set up various internal services and objects necessary for performing its duties, and the overhead of continuously doing so may be significant in high-performance scenarios. For these cases, EF Core can pool your context instance

The docs also explain this can cause problems, because the pooled Contexts maintain configuration from one use to another. If you use Global Query Filters for multitenancy, a pooled Context will keep the query filter it was first created with. The application has to handle this, otherwise one tenant could end up reading another's data.

Great explanation. Thanks.
